# Remove HTC Sync Manager from autostart

Tags: macos, user-account

Every time I start my laptop, the HTC Sync Manager is launched automatically. I **don't** mean the automounter which is started when you connect your phone. I mean the the HTC Sync Manager itself which is magically started and places its icon on the top of the screen:

> [image]

**Question:** How can I turn off that the HTC Sync Manager is started on every reboot?

I'm running a MacBook Pro with 10.9.

### Edit:

When I go to *Preferences->Users&Groups->LoginItems* then the HTC Manager does not appear there. The directory `/Library/StartupItems/` is empty as well.

### Edit:

I have made the folder content of certain startup daemons available as requested by Frizlab. Please find [here the contents of](https://gist.github.com/halirutan/fc6a9328a4390b89e1b1) the command

```
tree ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ /Library/LaunchAgents/ /Library/LaunchDaemons/ \
   /System/Library/LaunchAgents/ /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/
```

Additionally, I have reboot the MacBook without logging in and opened an `ssh` to it. It seems that the HTC application is started after the login. **After** I logged in, I find the following process

```
penny:~ patrick$ ps x | grep HTC
  232   ??  S      0:00.22 /Applications/HTC Sync Manager.app/Contents/Resources/HSMMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/HSMMonitor -runMode autoLaunched
  401 s001  S+     0:00.00 grep HTC
```

Comment: Can you list what's in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/, /Library/LaunchAgents/ & /Library/LaunchDaemons/?

Comment: So, I don't have HTC Sync Manager, but _usually_ if you open up the application, and go into it's own preferences (`cmd ,` ), there _may_ be a "start at runtime" or "launch at system start" checkbox. Just checking that if it exists, it's not checked.

Comment: @Frizlab See my edit.

Comment: Weird, I was really expecting to see the sync manager to be launched via a LaunchAgent or similar. Maybe it's in the System?

Do you know if the sync manager is launched _before_ your session is opened? If you know how to use ssh, simply reboot, do not log in, but connect via ssh to your computer from another device and check the running processes with `top` or `ps`. Or maybe (less reliable), log-in with the Guest user and check the running processes.

Comment: Try also listing /System/Library/LaunchAgents/ and /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/. (I didn't ask earlier because third-party softwares should _never_ install stuff in the system. Sadly, some do.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm spamming a bit. Don't hesitate to use https://gist.github.com/ to post the listing of the folders as they contain much more elements than the previous ones.

Comment: @RossMcKinley Unfortunately, this application does not have its own preferences as you know them from other applications. It has a *Settings* pane but there you can only adjust *import folders* and stuff.

Comment: @Frizlab Thanks for all your suggestions. The HTC application which is started automatically is actually stored as separate *monitor application* inside the resources of the application package. Please see all the information you requested as edit in my question. When the program is started *after* login, does this suggest it is stored in my personal init-files? Where could they hide something like this?

Comment: I think I got. Writing an answer, let me know how it goes! The trick was in the _name_ of the LaunchAgent.

Comment: @Frizlab I think it is `./LaunchAgents/com.nero.HSMMonitor.plist`.. Ahh, saw your comment. Yes, go on write up an answer.

Comment: It is written ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.nero.HSMMonitor.plist
```

Comment: If you want, I can develop my answer, to explain exactly what it does.

Comment: For me personally, you don't have to elaborate more because I'm using `launchctl` to set up environment variables for applications and I'm at least a bit familiar with it. It was just that I had no idea where automatically started applications are registered in OSX. Thank you very much for helping me tracking it down.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: For @bzelip (on Twitter): launchctl is the program to manage launchd, which is responsible for launching/making sure programs stay launched after certain events happen. How the programs should be launched is described in plist files. We tell launchctl to unload the given plist (the plist responsible for the launch of HTC Sync Manager), so it quits the manager. The "-w" flag tells launchctl to write the disabling in a private database, so the plist is not loaded after a reboot.

Comment: That plist doesn't exist

Answer (score 11):

**To disable HTC Sync Manager auto-mounting**
Launch terminal

Type
`diskutil info /Volumes/HTC Sync Manager`

Make a note of the Volume UUID.

Next
`sudo vifs`

Go to the bottom of the file
tap the `i` key

And paste the following
`UUID=YOURVOLUMEUUID none hfs rw,noauto`
Replacing YOURVOLUMEUUID with the one you made a note of earlier

Hit `Esc`
Then type the following to save.
`:wq`

You will be using "vim" in case you need help with the editor.

From [softwareispoetry](http://blog.softwareispoetry.com/2013/05/disable-htc-syc-manager-autostarting.html)

Edit: For stopping applications from autostarting go to Preferences > Users & Groups, then click on your user and remove HTC Sync Manager from your Login Items.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I didn't mean the *automounter*, I mean the HTC Sync Manager itself which is started on every reboot of my MacBook. Is there a chance that you know how I can turn this off? I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: What can I do if there is not such thing in the Login Items? The only entry is `iTunesHelper` and I am the only user on this machine.

Comment: Found this very useful as I wanted to do both this and control the LaunchAgents on my HTC One M8. Kudos.

Comment: I found this useful as well. The "HTC Sync Manager" Finder window was popping up in front every few minutes whenever I had my HTC One connected. Very annoying. This fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable the autorun volume on the phone:

Settings > Apps > All > HTC Sync Manager

Tap "Disable", for good measure tap "Force stop" and "Clear data"

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd /Applications/HTC\ Sync\ Manager.app/Contents/Resources/`
3. Rename HSMMonitor.app

   `mv HSMMonitor.app HSMMonitor.bak.app`